# first observation and count (find sequence length)

Tags: r

I have the following data.frame.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("abc","def","def","def", "ghi", "ghi"))
```

How can I count the number of observation of the column?

Comment: You can check `?table` i.e. `table(df$x)`

Comment: Total number or number of unique values?

Comment: observations meaning different values of the variable or total number of rows?

Comment: i would like to show 1,1,2,3,1,2 in another column, it would be the number of appreance.

Comment: You can use `with(df, ave(seq_along(x), x, FUN= seq_along))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the sequence by group ('x' column) is needed as the output, we can use `ave` from `base R`.  We group by 'x', and get the sequence (`seq_along`)

```
with(df, ave(seq_along(x), x, FUN= seq_along))
#[1] 1 1 2 3 1 2
```

---

With `dplyr`, we can use `row_number()` after grouping by 'x'.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(x) %>%
    mutate(Seq = row_number())
```